# Why is NotificationCompat needed?

Tags: android, notifications, compatibility

Specifically, I think anything done with NotificationCompat can be done using the default API (level 8).
What am I missing here? What does NotificationCompat introduce that cannot be done using 2.2 API?

Source: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html#Notes

Comment: i'm using the latest version of the Android SDK (in this moment, 4.4.2).
Is NotificationCompat still needed? or will Notification class work properly on all devices? (even Android 2.x and 3.x)
Just to make best practices in my projects :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use things like NotificationCompat.Builder#setLargeIcon(Bitmap) to allow you to take full advantage of Android 3.0+ with things like the large icon, while maintaining compatibility on versions of Android prior to 3.0 that do not support such things.

Comment: And these: mFullScreenIntent, mNumber, mTickerView, mContentInfo in addition to mLargeIcon. I hate it when people put 'm' as the first letter of a member. It just implies that they don't use good enough tools. I think that even emacs now colors class members differently.

Comment: Or it helps autocomplete while working inside a class or looking for member variables. Considering google does this internally seems to indicate some merit other than "not good enough tools."

Comment: `setLargeIcon(Bitmap)` with Notification.Builder: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLargeIcon(android.graphics.Bitmap)

Answer (score 2):

Though its old question, now NotificationCompat can also be used to create wearable specific notifications. More information on this google's developer guide.

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to use the NotificationCompat.Builder class, a compatibly version of Notification.Builder from  API 11+.  As its name suggests its an implementation of the builder pattern, which seems to be its main advantage over the pre Android 3.0 notifications.

Comment: The question is more about ability than tooling. "What", not "How".