# Android Notification.Builder vs NotificationCompat.Builder

Tags: android, cordova, android-notifications

Pretty much all the bits of sample code I see for Android notififactions appear to use NotificationCompat.  I have written up my own code using Notification.Builder.  It is not clear to me what benefits, if any, there might be in using NotificationCompat.Builder.  I hope that someone here might be able to explain the differences.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071086/why-is-notificationcompat-needed

Answer (score 8):

depends on what you are trying to do and what OS version's your app is compatible with but in most cases you would want to use `NotificationCompat` because that provides backwards compatibility where as if you wanted to provide that with the regular `Notification.Builder`  you would have to check what OS version the device has yourself to use API calls that are not in older versions