# Using android-support-v4.jar throws up errors

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-cli

This question follows up from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749482/android-notification-builder-vs-notificationcompat-builder).  Having established that the switch to NotificationCompat.Builder was probably worthwhile I set about doing the following

> **Please note**: I am working with Phonegap CLI here. The Phonegap application I am writing consists of one plugin that I am creating at the same time and the actual WebView side code in the project itself.

I modified my `plugin.xml` file

```
<lib-file src="src/android/libs/android-support-v4.jar"/>
```

To my `plugin/src/android/libs` folder I added `android-support-v4` which I found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/androidbigfacto/files/libs/android-support-v4.jar/download?use_mirror=heanet&r=http%3A%2F%2Fen.osdn.jp%2Fprojects%2Fsfnet_androidbigfacto%2Fdownloads%2Flibs%2Fandroid-support-v4.jar%2F&use_mirror=heanet).

To test if Phonegap was going to like the newcomer I first issued a `phonegap clean` and then proceeded to rebuild the project after removing and then putting back the plugin.  This threw up the error message

```
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 137

What does this mean?  Am I using the right version of the android-support-v4 library?  If not, where can I find the right version?

I hope that someone here will be able to point me in the right direction. I am using Phonegap CLI 6.4.2 with Java 7 and Node 4.5.

Comment: If you use Eclipse or Android Studio the android-support-v4 comes from the SDK (...\extras\android\support\v4). I assume Phonegap CLI also has/uses the android SDK.